# How to convert Dictionary<string, List<object>> into DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `Dictionary<string, AFValues>` which `AFValues` is a collection of type AFValue object.

A snapshot of what is behind the scene of the dictionary data structure:
[image]

The `Value` for each `Key` has this `AFValues` collection:
[image]

Then, this is what I have written so far to convert the dictionary into a data table.

```
private DataTable dataTable = null;    
private DataTable ConvertToDataTable(Dictionary<string, AFValues> dict)
        {
            using (dataTable = new DataTable())
            {
                if (dict.Count > 0)
                {
                    var headers = dict.Keys;
                    foreach (var colHeader in headers)
                    {
                        dataTable.Columns.Add(colHeader);
                    }

                    foreach (var row in dict)
                    {
                        DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                        foreach (var afVal in row.Value)
                        {
                            dataRow[row.Key] = afVal.Value;
                        }
                        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
                    }
                }
            }
            return dataTable;
        }
```

I have successfully created the `DataTable` columns based on the `dict.Keys` which is fairly straightforward.  However, my problem lies on how to correctly loop through `AFValues` and mapped each `AFValue` to their corresponding column (`dict.Key`)?

I have done my research, but couldn't find any related scenario which is the same as mine.

This is the returned `DataTable` based on the code above which is incorrect.

[image]

This should be the expected output (sample table)

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use a `using` Block. If you leave your using block the `DataTable` will be disposed.

Comment: @PinBack thanks for catching that.  You are right.  I don't need the `using` block because I need to returned the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a code block like this for your inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dict.Values.Max(item => item.Count()); i++)
{
    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

    foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
    {
        if (dict[key].Count > i)
            dataRow[key] = dict[key][i];
    }
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```

Comment: this one works like a charm, thank you, really appreciate it.